# Database explorer - Visual C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

1. I have `SQL server 2008 R2` installed with the default instance in my pc. Server name - `"GED"`, Database name -`"LOGIN"`.I want to access this database into my `C# winform`.
2. When i tried to add a connection from my C# database explorer (by keeping, `Datasource = ".\SQLEXPRESS"`), 
   it's giving me an

   > error-26-Error locating server/instance.
3. By keeping `Datasource = "."`, i am able to add the database, but it's giving me  a message database not exists you want to create it?
4. If I try to add the database by browsing, i am getting a info that i don't have the rights. But i am the administrator.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: please post the connection string ok, YOU are the administrator but what about the user you are connecting as? is that an admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

You can use `Environment.MachineName + "\\SQLEXPRESS"` as below

```
var connectionString = String.Format("Data Source = {0}\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = {1}; Integrated Security=SSPI ", Environment.MachineName, databaseName);
```

Comment: "Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\john\Documents\LOGIN.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True". This is my conn string

Comment: Have you verified the mdf file path?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LOGIN. This is the actual path of a created .mdf file. But if i try to browse and add, it's giving me admin rights pblm,

Comment: now i have 2 LOGIN.mdf files in the two diff paths.

Comment: Stop SQL Service and then move the file Login.MDF to other path for example D:\temp\login.mdf. Try this.

Comment: Your connection string is not wrong, I think only file path and its security issues are there. As I know you cannot access database files from Program File like folders even with admin rights

Comment: ok i will try and let you know. thank you. and also one more query. in C# database explorer we have option to use existing db file. if i move my db file from program files path to different path can i access?

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: thanks a lot man... it's resolved. it seems as you told we can't access the .mdf in program files path.